# .Formula Runtime error 1004 on some machines and not the other

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'll go straight to the point. Here is the line code that is geving me the error:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dados").Cells(16, 10).FormulaLocal = "=-(I16)+" & a & "+(" & c & "*((" & PiZi & " ^ " & d & ")*(I16 ^ " & d & ")/(" & Pc & " ^ " & d & ")))"
```

The above code works on my home machine (where created) and does not work on my lab or work machine

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dados").Cells(16, 10).Formula = "=-(I16)+" & a & "+(" & c & "*((" & PiZi & " ^ " & d & ")*(I16 ^ " & d & ")/(" & Pc & " ^ " & d & ")))"
```

And the second one works on my lab and work machine, but does not in my home machine.
The only difference is Formula and FormulaLocal. I know FormulaLocal could give me errors because of different installations of excel might have different language.... but shouldn't Formula work everywhere?

Also, if I change cells to R16C9 instead of I16 it works in my home machine and bugs in others. I really want a code that can work everywhere here. Can someone help? Thanks

P.S.: Variables are all ok and well defined, but the issue is probably that they have decimals, thus the comma or dot issue

Debug.Print (With FormulaLocal) gives me:

```
=-(I16)+0,549840740436919+(0,0513418101762096*((604,958825198337 ^ 1,04086742681856)*(I16 ^ 1,04086742681856)/(49,44 ^ 1,04086742681856)))
```

Comment: Difficult to know what the problem might be without seeing the missing pieces - `Debug.Print` the formula and add the output to the question.  Copy the output and try adding it to the cell via the formula bar - do you get an error?  If Yes, what error?  `Formula` should work if the string you're passing is a valid formula in a version of Excel with English as the language setting.

Comment: As already mentioned the first thing to do is Debug.Print and inspect the formula. As is this means nothing. You have _five_ variables going into that string whose value is unknown. It's quite possible the variable values are the issue

Comment: Completely forgot to mention that yes, variables are the issue because they have decimals.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better solutions, mainly on the dumb way i used that if, but this now works on every machine i have. Thanks everyone.

```
...
bloqueio = 5
On Error GoTo alternativa
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dados").Cells(16, 10).Formula = "=-(I16)+" & a & "+(" & c & "*((" & PiZi & " ^ " & d & ")*(I16 ^ " & d & ")/(" & Pc & " ^ " & d & ")))"
If bloqueio = 0 Then
alternativa:
    On Error GoTo -1
    On Error GoTo Erro
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dados").Cells(16, 10).FormulaLocal = "=-(I16)+" & a & "+(" & c & "*((" & PiZi & " ^ " & d & ")*(I16 ^ " & d & ")/(" & Pc & " ^ " & d & ")))"
End If
On Error GoTo -1
...
```